# Util javascript to perform normalisation for number

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to trim my 5 or more than 5 digit number 12345 to

12.34k

to fit it in my small box. Is there any util to use?

Answer (score 0):

you can divide it by 1000 and then specify the number of digits you want using **toFixed()**

```js
let x = 12345;
x = x/1000;
x = x.toFixed(2);
x = x + "k";

console.log(x)
```